# Error handling in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

Oddly I'm having a hard time finding good docs about basic error handling in rails. I'd appreciate any good links as well as thoughts on a handling errors in a really basic method like this:

```
  def self.get_record(id)
    People.first( :conditions => ["id = ?", id] )
  end
```

1) I could verify that id != nil, and that it's numeric.

2) I could also then verify that a record is found.

Is there anything else?

Are both #1 and #2 recommended practice? In both cases would you simply create a flash message with the error and display it, or is that giving away too much information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, this is just like `People.find(id)`, except that `find` raises an error.

However, `People.find_by_id(id)` returns nil if no record is found, which I suspect takes care of all you need. You don't need to check that what you put into ActiveRecord is the correct data type and the like; it handles SQL injection risks, so to check ahead of time would not affect actual behavior.

If we're just looking at the `show` action, though, there's an even more elegant way: rather than using `find_by_id` and checking for nil, use `find`, let an error bubble up, and let the controller catch it with [`rescue_from`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from). (By default, in production, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will be caught and rescued by showing a generic 404, but you can customize this behavior if necessary.)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found

  def show
    @user = User.find params[:id]
  end

  protected
    def not_found
      flash[:error] = "User not found"
      redirect_to users_path
    end
end
```

Code untested, for illustrative purposes only ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do flash[:notice]'s insted just say that "Record not found"

The two things required by you can be done as follows:

1) I could verify that id != nil, and that it's numeric.

```
def self.get_record(id)
  People.first( :conditions => ["id = ?", id] ) if id.integer? unless id.blank?
end
```

2) I could also then verify that a record is found.

```
def self.get_record(id)
  @people = People.first( :conditions => ["id = ?", id] ) if id.integer? unless id.blank?
  flash[:notice] = @people.blank? # this will print true/false depending on value in @people
end
```

Hope it works for you. :D